# Template compiler limitation?

Tags: c++, templates, static-polymorphism

This error is difficult to explain, but it comes from using static polymorphism to a bit of an extreme.

See the following code.  In the code, if I derive a templatized class from a templatized class, and then use a templatized function with more than one template parameter, I get a less than helpful compile error of

```
error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'bool' to binary 'operator<'
```

This issue does not occur when the derived class is not itself templatized, oddly enough, or when the templatized function only has one template argument.  I'm totally stumped, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using gcc 4.7.2 on fedora 7.

```
template <class Derived>
class BasicTemplate
{
    protected:
    template<bool param1, int param2, typename Param3>
    void templatizedFunction(const Param3 & input)
    {
    }
};

template <class C>
class DerivedTemplate : public BasicTemplate<DerivedTemplate<C> >
{
    using Base = BasicTemplate<DerivedTemplate<C> >;
    public:
    template <bool param1, int param2, typename Param3>
    void templatizedFunction(const Param3 & input)
    {
        Base::templatizedFunction<param1, param2>(input);
    }
    C myData_;
};

class DerivedNonTemplate : public BasicTemplate<DerivedNonTemplate>
{
    using Base = BasicTemplate<DerivedNonTemplate>;
    public:
    template <bool param1, int param2, typename Param3>
    void templatizedFunction(const Param3 & input)
    {
        Base::templatizedFunction<param1, param2>(input);
    }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedTemplate<int> derivedTemplate;
    DerivedNonTemplate derivedNonTemplate;
    derivedTemplate.templatizedFunction<false, 1>(1);
    derivedNonTemplate.templatizedFunction<false, 1>(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `using Base = BasicTemplate<DreivedTemplate<C> >;` typo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords may be relevant, you might be missing a `template` keyword.

Comment: fixed the typo in the example code--this isn't the exact code I was using to compile so not relevant

Comment: Well if I knew I'd be answering :-) I'd guess something like `Base::template templatizedFunction<...>(...)`, but that could be totally wrong.

Comment: Yes, the error occurs because of the lacking `template` keyword.

Comment: Mat was exactly right.  I needed to call
Base::template templatizedFunction<param1, param2>(input); from within my derived class.  Thanks!